# Gridwise application of the bisection method

Tags: python, numpy, bisection

I need to find roots for a generalized state space. That is, I have a discrete grid of dimensions `grid=AxBx(...)xX`, of which I do not know ex ante how many dimensions it has (the solution should be applicable to any `grid.size`) .

I want to find the roots (`f(z) = 0`) for every state `z` inside `grid` using the [bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method). Say `remainder` contains `f(z)`, and I know `f'(z) < 0`. Then I need to

- increase `z`  if `remainder` > 0
- decrease `z` if `remainder` < 0

Wlog, say the matrix `history`of shape `(grid.shape, T)` contains the history of earlier values of `z` for every point in the grid and I need to increase `z` (since `remainder` > 0). I will then need to select `zAlternative` inside `history[z, :]` that is the "smallest of those, that are larger than `z`". In pseudo-code, that is:

```
zAlternative =  hist[z,:][hist[z,:] > z].min()
```

[I had asked this earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930749/python-scipy-find-bounded-min-max-of-a-matrix). The solution I was given was

```
b = sort(history[..., :-1], axis=-1)
mask = b > history[..., -1:]
index = argmax(mask, axis=-1)
indices = tuple([arange(j) for j in b.shape[:-1]])
indices = meshgrid(*indices, indexing='ij', sparse=True)
indices.append(index)
indices = tuple(indices)
lowerZ = history[indices]

b = sort(history[..., :-1], axis=-1)
mask = b <= history[..., -1:]
index = argmax(mask, axis=-1)
indices = tuple([arange(j) for j in b.shape[:-1]])
indices = meshgrid(*indices, indexing='ij', sparse=True)
indices.append(index)
indices = tuple(indices)
higherZ = history[indices]

newZ = history[..., -1]
criterion = 0.05
increase = remainder > 0 + criterion
decrease = remainder < 0 - criterion
newZ[increase] = 0.5*(newZ[increase] + higherZ[increase])
newZ[decrease] = 0.5*(newZ[decrease] + lowerZ[decrease])
```

However, this code ceases to work for me. I feel extremely bad about admitting it, but I never understood the magic that is happening with the indices, therefore I unfortunately need help.

What the code *actually does*, it to give me the *lowest* respectively the *highest*. That is, if I fix on two specific `z` values:

```
history[z1] = array([0.3, 0.2, 0.1])
history[z2] = array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
```

I will get `higherZ[z1]` = `0.3` and `lowerZ[z2] = 0.1`, that is, the extrema. The correct value for both cases would have been `0.2`. What's going wrong here?

If needed, in order to generate testing data, you can use something along the lines of

```
history = tile(array([0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.15, 0.13])[newaxis,newaxis,:], (10, 20, 1))
remainder = -1*ones((10, 20))
```

to test the second case.

**Expected outcome**

I adjusted the `history` variable above, to give test cases for both upwards and downwards. Expected outcome would be

```
lowerZ = 0.1 * ones((10,20))
higherZ = 0.15 * ones((10,20))
```

Which is, for every point `z` in history[z, :], the next highest previous value (`higherZ`) and the next smallest previous value (`lowerZ`). Since all points `z` have exactly the same history (`[0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.15, 0.13]`), they will all have the same values for `lowerZ` and `higherZ`. Of course, in general, the histories for each `z` will be different and hence the two matrices will contain potentially different values on every grid point.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "to find the roots (`f(z) = 0`) for every state `z` inside `grid`"? Do you mean that `f` is a function of an additional variable, that is you want to find `φ(z)` such that `f(z, φ(z)) = 0` for any `z`, or do you want to find the set of `z ∈ grid` for which `f` evaluates to zero, or do you only want to find _a_ root within `grid`?

Comment: Does ```history``` contain each *guess* of ```z``` that has been tried in the bisection algorithm?  For the testing data you spec'd, ```history.shape``` is (10,20,3) - does that represent 10 guesses of ```z``` where ```z.shape``` is (20,3)?

Comment: @wwii: the history for every `z` is in the last dimension, `-1`. Hence, we have `10x20` data that all have `3` observations: `(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)`. Given that `remainder < 0`, for every observation in that `10x20` data set, we need to find the "next smallest value" - `0.2`

Comment: @Phillip: I am excluding `f` from the code given, I am only curious about the updating mechanism. In the example given, `remainder` will contain a `10x20` matrix that indicates whether the `grid` values need to be updated upwards or downwards. I am interested in finding the "next highest" or "next smallest" value inside `history` - the matrices `lowerZ` and `higherZ` in the code snippet provided.

Comment: @FooBar: Do I get you correctly: Given a grid `z` and an arbitrary  index `i` and a history array of grids `H`, you want to find `min([ H[k][i] for k in len(H) if H[k][i] > z[i]])`, only for all `i` and in an efficient manner?

Comment: That is my goal, correct. However, note, that my shape of `H`, as you call it, is `z`x"length of history" `+ 2`. This will not be relevant for the answer, but so you know what I do: I provide the global minimum and maximum for the bisection in `(z, 0)` and `(z, 1)`, and the initial guess in `(z, 2)`, for every `z` in my  `grid`. Then, with every iteration `i` of the bisection, the next guess will be stored `(z, i+2)`. Therefore, the shape of my `history` (your `H`) is `(grid.shape, h)`, where `h` is any integer `> 2`.

Comment: ```history``` contains **all** *guesses* that have been made, ```history[...,2:]```,  as well as the global min and max? With this test data, what do expect newZ to be?

Comment: @wwii see my earlier comment  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098205/gridwise-application-of-the-bisection-method?noredirect=1#comment37260127_24098205

Comment: I extended the code to generate the sample code and also wrote a short paragraph about expected outcome.

Comment: I'm curious - why are you keeping a history of guesses instead of just hi, low, current?

Comment: I'll look into your answers tomorrow when I'm in my office. If it's really up to doing `>` instead of `>=`, I'll be quite mad with myself. For your curiosity, that's mainly for logging. Want to see afterwards the actual speed of convergence (for a larger neighbourhood), in order to perhaps tweak performance at cost of the precision window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compared what you posted here to [the solution for your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19932188/2823755) and noticed some differences.

For the *smaller* z, you said

```
mask = b > history[..., -1:]
index = argmax(mask, axis=-1)
```

They said:

```
mask = b >= a[..., -1:]
index = np.argmax(mask, axis=-1) - 1
```

For the *larger* z, you said

```
mask = b <= history[..., -1:]
index = argmax(mask, axis=-1)
```

They said:

```
mask = b > a[..., -1:]
index = np.argmax(mask, axis=-1)
```

Using [the solution for your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19932188/2823755), I get:

```
import numpy as np
history = np.tile(np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.15, 0.13])[np.newaxis,np.newaxis,:], (10, 20, 1))
remainder = -1*np.ones((10, 20))

a = history

# b is a sorted ndarray excluding the most recent observation
# it is sorted along the observation axis
b = np.sort(a[..., :-1], axis=-1)

# mask is a boolean array, comparing the (sorted)
# previous observations to the current observation - [..., -1:]
mask = b > a[..., -1:]

# The next 5 statements build an indexing array.
# True evaluates to one and False evaluates to zero.
# argmax() will return the index of the first True,
# in this case along the last (observations) axis.
# index is an array with the shape of z (2-d for this test data).
# It represents the index of the next greater
# observation for every 'element' of z.
index = np.argmax(mask, axis=-1)

# The next two statements construct arrays of indices
# for every element of z - the first n-1 dimensions of history.
indices = tuple([np.arange(j) for j in b.shape[:-1]])
indices = np.meshgrid(*indices, indexing='ij', sparse=True)

# Adding index to the end of indices (the last dimension of history)
# produces a 'group' of indices that will 'select' a single observation
# for every 'element' of z
indices.append(index)
indices = tuple(indices)
higherZ = b[indices]

mask = b >= a[..., -1:]
# Since b excludes the current observation, we want the
# index just before the next highest observation for lowerZ,
# hence the minus one.
index = np.argmax(mask, axis=-1) - 1
indices = tuple([np.arange(j) for j in b.shape[:-1]])
indices = np.meshgrid(*indices, indexing='ij', sparse=True)
indices.append(index)
indices = tuple(indices)
lowerZ = b[indices]
assert np.all(lowerZ == .1)
assert np.all(higherZ == .15)
```

which seems to work

Comment: This is much faster than the [sliding_window solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24152353/2823755).

Comment: I went mad. Like, it can't be the `>` vs `>=`. And it wasn't (at least not only). `higherZ = b[indices]` in your code, while in mine it was `higherZ = history[indices]`.

Comment: I had to figure out how that indexing works, hopefully I will remember it when I need it.  I added comments to the code.

Comment: A bit of disclaimer - Although I was able to figure out how it works, I could not have come up with that on my own.

Answer (score 0):

z-shaped arrays for the next highest and lowest observation in `history`
relative to the current observation, given the current observation is `history[...,-1:]`

This constructs the higher and lower arrays by manipulating the strides of `history`
to make it easier to iterate over the observations of each element of z.
This is accomplished using `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` and an n-dim generalzed
function found at [Efficient Overlapping Windows with Numpy](http://www.johnvinyard.com/blog/?p=268) - I will include it's source at the end

There is a single python loop that has 200 iterations for `history.shape` of (10,20,x).

```
import numpy as np

history = np.tile(np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.15, 0.13])[np.newaxis,np.newaxis,:], (10, 20, 1))
remainder = -1*np.ones((10, 20))

z_shape = final_shape = history.shape[:-1]
number_of_observations = history.shape[-1]
number_of_elements_in_z = np.product(z_shape)

# manipulate histories to efficiently iterate over
# the observations of each "element" of z
s = sliding_window(history, (1,1,number_of_observations))
# s.shape will be (number_of_elements_in_z, number_of_observations)

# create arrays of the next lower and next higher observation
lowerZ = np.zeros(number_of_elements_in_z)
higherZ = np.zeros(number_of_elements_in_z)
for ndx, observations in enumerate(s):
    current_observation = observations[-1]
    a = np.sort(observations)
    lowerZ[ndx] = a[a < current_observation][-1]
    higherZ[ndx] = a[a > current_observation][0]

assert np.all(lowerZ == .1)
assert np.all(higherZ == .15)
lowerZ = lowerZ.reshape(z_shape)
higherZ = higherZ.reshape(z_shape)
```

#### `sliding_window` from [Efficient Overlapping Windows with Numpy](http://www.johnvinyard.com/blog/?p=268)

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as ast
from itertools import product

def norm_shape(shape):
    '''
    Normalize numpy array shapes so they're always expressed as a tuple, 
    even for one-dimensional shapes.

    Parameters
        shape - an int, or a tuple of ints

    Returns
        a shape tuple

    from http://www.johnvinyard.com/blog/?p=268
    '''
    try:
        i = int(shape)
        return (i,)
    except TypeError:
        # shape was not a number
        pass

    try:
        t = tuple(shape)
        return t
    except TypeError:
        # shape was not iterable
        pass

    raise TypeError('shape must be an int, or a tuple of ints')


def sliding_window(a,ws,ss = None,flatten = True):
    '''
    Return a sliding window over a in any number of dimensions

    Parameters:
        a  - an n-dimensional numpy array
        ws - an int (a is 1D) or tuple (a is 2D or greater) representing the size 
             of each dimension of the window
        ss - an int (a is 1D) or tuple (a is 2D or greater) representing the 
             amount to slide the window in each dimension. If not specified, it
             defaults to ws.
        flatten - if True, all slices are flattened, otherwise, there is an 
                  extra dimension for each dimension of the input.

    Returns
        an array containing each n-dimensional window from a

    from http://www.johnvinyard.com/blog/?p=268
    '''

    if None is ss:
        # ss was not provided. the windows will not overlap in any direction.
        ss = ws
    ws = norm_shape(ws)
    ss = norm_shape(ss)

    # convert ws, ss, and a.shape to numpy arrays so that we can do math in every 
    # dimension at once.
    ws = np.array(ws)
    ss = np.array(ss)
    shape = np.array(a.shape)


    # ensure that ws, ss, and a.shape all have the same number of dimensions
    ls = [len(shape),len(ws),len(ss)]
    if 1 != len(set(ls)):
        error_string = 'a.shape, ws and ss must all have the same length. They were{}'
        raise ValueError(error_string.format(str(ls)))

    # ensure that ws is smaller than a in every dimension
    if np.any(ws > shape):
        error_string = 'ws cannot be larger than a in any dimension. a.shape was {} and ws was {}'
        raise ValueError(error_string.format(str(a.shape),str(ws)))

    # how many slices will there be in each dimension?
    newshape = norm_shape(((shape - ws) // ss) + 1)
    # the shape of the strided array will be the number of slices in each dimension
    # plus the shape of the window (tuple addition)
    newshape += norm_shape(ws)
    # the strides tuple will be the array's strides multiplied by step size, plus
    # the array's strides (tuple addition)
    newstrides = norm_shape(np.array(a.strides) * ss) + a.strides
    strided = ast(a,shape = newshape,strides = newstrides)
    if not flatten:
        return strided

    # Collapse strided so that it has one more dimension than the window.  I.e.,
    # the new array is a flat list of slices.
    meat = len(ws) if ws.shape else 0
    firstdim = (np.product(newshape[:-meat]),) if ws.shape else ()
    dim = firstdim + (newshape[-meat:])
    # remove any dimensions with size 1
    dim = filter(lambda i : i != 1,dim)
    return strided.reshape(dim)
```